# How can I avoid clicking ok button

Tags: axapta

I am working with axproxies and want to avoid clicking of ok button. its pretty simple to give a command button.ok.click(), but what is happening here is, If I move to any other box when the axproxie is running, the application gets struck. I think thats because of movement in mouse pointer. Do I have a way, where I can avoid the mouse clicks for ok and submit??? any reply would be of great help..... thanks in advance...

Comment: What the heck is axproxie? What is the exact context?

Answer (score 1):

Alt-O, if you can accept a keyboard shortcut.